# Java version names in Sun's bug database

Tags: java

In
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6525150
it says
Release Fixed 7(b14), 6u2(b01) (Bug ID:2147561)

What does 6u2 mean? (Am I right in assuming it as 1.6.0_02 ?)

Answer (score 2):

yes, release 6 update 2. Also, (b01) is build 01

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are right. :) u2 -> Update 2