# How to find jdk release from build numbers in sun bug database

Tags: java, jvm-crash

I am experiencing a bug in the JDK that I'm using, and I have found a [reference](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7042153) to it in Sun's (Oracle's) bug database. It says the fixed versions are hs21(b13), 7(b143), but I don't know how to figure out which release of the JDK the fix is in.

I have seen this post: [Java version names in Sun's bug database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196170/java-version-names-in-suns-bug-database), but it doesn't really answer my question.

Edit: I'm trying to figure out which release of JDK (e.g. 1.7.0_07) corresponds to 7(b143). In other words, I want to know the earliest released version that the fix for this bug is in.

Comment: It has to be a `java` on your system, so I would do `java -version` to give you the version information and find a match.

Answer (score 0):

`hs` is for **HotSpot** and `7` is for the **JRE**.

So JRE 7, build 143 and HotSpot JVM 21.0 build b13

If you do `java -version` in a console prompt, it'll tell you what JDK and build you have.

The bug you are referring to shows what environment it was detected in:

```
# JRE version: 7.0-b139
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b09 mixed mode, sharing solaris-x86 )
```

So it's happening in `7(b139)` and `hs21(b09)`
and fixed in `7(b143)` and `hs21(b13)`

I hope this helps.

Comment: I understand that. What I don't get is how JRE 7.0-b139 corresponds to a 'release'. For example, I see the latest release is JRE 1.7.0_07 from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u-relnotes-515228.html

Comment: It just means they've released up to b10 (`The full version string for this update release is 1.7.0_07-b10`). So basically the defect fix your are looking for has not been released. They don't just just release after each bug fix, the fix could be in the next 1.7 or even 1.8

Comment: Hard to imagine a bug reported to be closed in 2011 has not yet made it into a release yet. After reading it over, I think what I missed is that 7(b143) is talking about version 7.0 (the first release of 7). Builds corresponding to updates would look like this: 7u1(b123). I would imagine that 1.7.0_1-b08 (the first update release) would have all fixes from 7.0.