# Java compiler fails when compiling simple program

Tags: java, compilation

I have problem with the Java compiler. I simplified my code to:

```
package a;

public class Base {
  // compiles if this is made public or an int
  protected Integer value = 0;
}

---

package b; // must be in a separate package

import a.Base;

public class Sub extends Base {
  public void increment() {
    System.out.println(super.value);
    value++;
    super.value = 1;
    super.value = super.value + 1;
    // this line crashes the compiler; the others all work
    super.value++;
  }
}
```

after compiling I'm getting:

```
Information:java: An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_51). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
Information:java: java.lang.NullPointerException
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.isSubClass(Symbol.java:1020)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.accessClass(Lower.java:1108)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.accessSymbol(Lower.java:983)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.access(Lower.java:1220)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitSelect(Lower.java:3855)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2382)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitVarDef(Lower.java:3547)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:852)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translateVarDefs(TreeTranslator.java:78)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitLetExpr(Lower.java:3859)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$LetExpr.accept(JCTree.java:2426)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitLetExpr(Lower.java:3860)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitUnary(Lower.java:3319)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCUnary.accept(JCTree.java:1746)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitExec(TreeTranslator.java:245)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCExpressionStatement.accept(JCTree.java:1296)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:162)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitBlock(Lower.java:3561)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:909)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitMethodDef(TreeTranslator.java:145)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitMethodDefInternal(Lower.java:2828)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitMethodDef(Lower.java:2737)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:778)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitClassDef(Lower.java:2508)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2390)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translateTopLevelClass(Lower.java:3932)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.desugar(JavaCompiler.java:1512)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.desugar(JavaCompiler.java:1356)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2(JavaCompiler.java:901)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:860)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:168)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:382)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:296)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:204)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:176)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1202)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:877)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:948)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:840)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:665)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:372)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:193)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:137)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:293)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:124)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:242)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
Information:java:   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
Information:java:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
Information:java:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
Information:java:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
Information:java:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'testAGH'
Information:2015-10-23 14:23 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 671ms
Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

Why does Java fail to compile this?

Comment: Same behaviour with 1.8.0_60. Whether you program compiles or not the compiler should not throw an exception so you should probably file a bug.

Comment: *Why java fails to compile*: the error message says why: there is a bug in the compiler.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.8.0_66 and java compiler is still crashing. I will file a bug.

Comment: I run your code without any problem in Java jdk1.7.0_79

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clearly a compiler bug. You should file a bug as the output instructs, but since you asked *why* I'll try to explore that :)

The [JDK langtools repo](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools) contains the code for `javac`.  I browsed through several different [builds](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/tags) but wasn't able to find a version with line numbers that matched up with the stack trace (I'm not sure how to [match a Java version to a build number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12606889/113632)), so I'm going off of the most recent build, [b132](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/rev/jdk8-b132).

As you can see, the underlying issue is a `NullPointerException` in [`com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Symbol.java) in [`Symbol.ClassSymbol.isSubClass()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Symbol.java#l1004). So that's the source of the issue.  Looking higher in the stack trace we can see `access()` calls `accessSymbol()` then `accessClass()` before reaching `isSubClass()`.  So we can infer that the compiler is trying to verify the subclass is permitted to access `super.value` at the time it fails.

Without knowing which line the NPE is occurring on it's hard to pinpoint the exact problem, so unfortunately here things get fuzzy. Since this failure only occurs when we try to increment-and-set (`++` or `+=`) the field, and only if we refer to it as `super.value`, we'd expect to see some code related to casting, autoboxing, assignment, or arithmetic.  Alas nothing in `isSubClass()` really seems related to any of that.

My guess, given that there doesn't appear to be anything incriminating in `isSubClass()`, is that [`Lower.accessClass()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Lower.java#l1100) is passing a `null` into `isSubClass()`.  There are three values passed to `isSubClass()` in this method: the field [`currentClass`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Lower.java#l120) (as `c`, this is "the currently enclosing class"), `sym.owner` (I think `sym` is our `value` field, I don't know what its `owner` is but presumably the class it's declared in), and `types`, which looks to always be set to a non-null value.  So it's either `currentClass` or `sym.owner`, and there are references to `sym.owner` that would NPE in [`Lower.access()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Lower.java#l1135) earlier, so that also seems to be non-null.

So I'll hazard that the culprit is `Lower.currentClass` is null for some reason.  Since `currentClass` is a package-private non-final field, I'm not going to bother trying to determine if it can be `null` at this time or not, but it appears possible.  There are several other possible culprits in `isSubClass()` of course, so I could well be wrong.

Inconclusive, but I hope this was informative!  I'll certainly update if I learn more.